# Electromotive force in proximity of a black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gravity, black-holes, batteries

Let's suppose I have an 1,5V battery hanging on two wires. Then, imagine that I orbit a black hole from a safe distance and lower this battery towards a black hole. The battery is now located on 2R mark, i.e., the distance from the event horizon (as seen from my orbit) to the battery is the same as the radius of the black hole.

What's the voltage reading between the ends of those two wires? If I put electrical load between them, will it able to measure any difference compared to default state where I did not lower the battery towards the black hole?

Comment: Why are you assuming the EMF is affected by gravity?

Comment: I'm not assuming anything, negative answer is still an answer.

Comment: @Gert: I think this is "either you measure a voltage, in which case, the information that the battery is connected to the wires is leaving the event horizon, or you measure nothing, in which case, gravity is affecting the EMF.  You could make the experiment worse by having the wires sit stationarily at some fixed radius, and then have wires unspool or telescope out into the horizon

Comment: Please note I have never said anything about going *into* the horizon.